# When is \if@nobreak set to \iftrue or \iffalse?

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, conditionals, latex-base

In my [answer to a question on page breaking](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12034/how-to-make-longtable-respect-nopagebreak-in-the-beginning/19576#19576), I used a private switch that the user had to set by hand to prevent tables which start just after a section from breaking (at the first line).

It seems that `\@nobreaktrue` is set after each heading, and restored as soon as the next paragraph begins (see definition of `\@afterheading`).

Is this the only place where `\if@nobreak` is altered? Am I right that the intent of this switch is to indicate places where macros should avoid at all costs to insert page breaks?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From source2e:

> `\if@nobreak` Switch used to avoid page
>   breaks caused by `\label` after a
>   section heading, etc. It should be
>   GLOBALLY set true after the `\nobreak`
>   and globally set false by the next
>   invocation of `\everypar`. Commands that
>   reset `\everypar` should globally set it
>   false if appropriate.